# SQL Server DBCC Check Fail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, database-administration, ssms-2016

If I set DBCC CHECK to run as part of a job; will the job fail (and subsequently alert me) if an allocation error/consistency error is found?

```
USE [mydb]
GO
DBCC CHECKDB(N'mydb')  WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if the job fails than there is something wrong with database consistency or resource availability, in either case administrator have to rectify the issue. There is an option of configuring "Alerts" in the job that will trigger an email etc to inform certain group or people, if proper monitoring is not available.